# PowerShell - Retrieving files on a remote server via the click of a button on a .aspx web page

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, asp.net, powershell-4.0

Here's my problem:

I have a PowerShell script which runs successfully when I execute the script from PowerShell itself.
However, when the script is called via the click of a button on a web page, it fails.

The script itself connects to a remote server (via a function) and retrieves some files. When it fails from the button, it calls the function to connect to the remote server but isn't able to actually connect - it says that an argument is null or empty.

Note: Several other processes run successfully before this part of the script is reached, so it does appear to be a problem with connecting to a remote server from a web page button.

Does anyone know a reason why this may happen? Is there a reason why this might not work when run from a button on a website (despite the script running successfully otherwise)??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

John-Boy

#### EDIT

The script is huge but essentially it boils down to using some pre-defined connection properties and then a function using the computer name, username and password to connect to the remote computer. I.e:
function Connect()
{
    $o = New-PS
    $o.UserID   = "userID"
    $o.Password = "pswd"
    $o.Computer = "computer.app.net"
    return $o
}

The .aspx button simply opens and runs PowerShell and then runs my script. It runs all of the script within the PowerShell program successfully until it has to connect to this remote computer.

Perhaps it is an authentication issue but where might I add this in?

Comment: What is the script and hows does the aspx page call it? If the script uses credentials for remote connectivity then authentication is a likely culprit.

Comment: The information you provided is inadequate to help anyone else troubleshoot this issue. If you are unwilling to post _relevant_ code then add extra code to output critical variables, this will help you debug it.

Comment: No it is not inadequate. The question is about whether there are known issues with logging on to a remote server via a button on a .aspx webpage.... Doesn't have to be specific code. Troglodyte.

Comment: Probably the best way to get people to help you is insulting them... And then posting code that does not run at all.. What in the world is `New-Ps`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess at what is going on. It would be nice to know what command you're using to connect to the remote server, i.e. PowerShell remoting or some other tecnology.

I'll assume you're trying to use PowerShell Remoting, e.g. `Invoke-Command`. Unfortunately, PowerShell Remoting requires the account to be an Administrator on the remote computer. With explicit credentials, PowerShell will use the identity of the user running your IIS app pool.

Also, can you post the exact error message you're receiving and the code causing the error?